# Revealing a div behind another with scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla, parallax

I'm currently working on a joomla website in which I have multiple modules such as :

```
<div class = "mod_slideshow"></div>
<div class = "blog-featured"></div>
<div class = "mod_example"></div>
```

and I would like them to overlap over one another just like in this website : http://www.lyonaeroports-t1.com/fr/la-qualite-de-service-au-coeur-du-projet

So far, the only thing I managed to to is to toggle the position to "fixed" of every div depending on window.scrollTop. The div scrolls over the previous one but doesn't "appear" juste like in the website mentioned.

I really don't know how to do this, any help would be very welcome.

Comment: This is named "parallax scrolling effect" - Add this to your tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This effect that they are achieving is called "**Parallax Scrolling effect**"

The example that you have shown is actually very easy - your magic CSS property is `background-attachment: fixed`. Consider the below HTML

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/ObEpBQ)

**HTML**

```
<div class="mod_slideshow"></div>
<div class="blog-featured"></div>
<div class="mod_example"></div>
```

the appropriate **CSS** code should be (no JS required for this)

```
.mod_slideshow {
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.blog-featured {
  background: url("http://www.aee-community.com/wp-content/uploads/rtMedia/users/1/2016/09/2429637D00000578-0-image-a-284_1419003100839.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.mod_example {
  background: url("http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-25252601,width-640,resizemode-4/stunning-images-of-the-space.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Simple :-) just give a `height` to your div with the fixed background. Remember the div itself is NOT fixed, the background image is.

```css
.mod_slideshow {
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.blog-featured {
  background: url("http://www.aee-community.com/wp-content/uploads/rtMedia/users/1/2016/09/2429637D00000578-0-image-a-284_1419003100839.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.mod_example {
  background: url("http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-25252601,width-640,resizemode-4/stunning-images-of-the-space.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="mod_slideshow"></div>
<div class="blog-featured"></div>
<div class="mod_example"></div>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you very, VERY much sir ! I would have never expected this needed only CSS.

Comment: No worries.. Cheers!